# Prove $\frac{\sin (2016x)}{2016x}<\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How can we prove that $$\frac{\sin (2016x)}{2016x}<\frac{\sin x}{x}$$ with $x$ close to/near $0$

I don't know where to start from, but I think that we need to examine distinct cases of $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: On what interval(s) shall that inequality hold? It doesn't hold on all of $(0,+\infty)$, for example.

Comment: It will suffice to just look for x>0 because when x<0 it also ends up being the same thing

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right. Maybe it is provable near/close to 0? So that limits can also play their game... But both functions are dense near 0, so I am not sure...

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$, so you certainly have $\frac{\sin cx}{cx} < \frac{\sin x}{x}$ on $\bigl(0, \frac{\pi}{c}\bigr]$ for $c > 1$. Well, certainly on $\bigl(0,\min \bigl\{\pi, \frac{2\pi}{c}\bigr\}\bigr)$, since $\frac{\sin cx}{cx} < 0$ on $\bigl(\frac{\pi}{c}, \min \bigl\{\pi, \frac{2\pi}{c}\bigr\}\bigr)$.

Comment: Case I: For $x>0$, $\frac{\sin(2016 x)}{2016x} < \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, since $x>0$ then $\sin(2016 x)<2016\sin x <2016$ which is true. Similarly, if $x<0$. For $x=0$, on the left hand side set $u=2016x$ then $u\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ so that we have $1<1$ in this case the inequality not valid  exactly at $x=0$. To keep the inequality, let us write $
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{\sin \left( {2016x} \right)}}{{2016x}} < \frac{{\sin x}}{x},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x \ne 0 \\ 
  \\ 
 \frac{{\sin \left( {2016x} \right)}}{{2016x}} \le \frac{{\sin x}}{x},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$

Comment: @mwomath Why is $\sin (2016x)<2016\sin x$?

Comment: since $x>0$, multiplying both sides by $x$ then $\sin 2016x < 2016 \sin x$. For $x<0$, we have x=$-y$, $y>0$, so that $\frac{\sin 2016(-y)}{-2016y}=\frac{\sin(2016y)}{2016y}$ (since $\sin$ is odd), so goes similarly.

Comment: @mwomath You have a circle in your proof. You take as granted the inequality I provided and you don't prove it based on equivalences because the last step is not equivalent. By "the last step" I mean this: $\sin (2016x)<2016\sin x<2016x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you write a full (with all austere, mathematical explanations) proof as answer to this question? I would greatly appreciate it so as to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll treat the more general problem: compare $\;\dfrac{\sin cx}{cx}$ and $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ for any number $c>0$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Since $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ is an even function, it is enough to consider the case $x>0$. We'll  denote $f$ the continuous extension of  $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ to $\mathbf R$. 
One easily checks that $f$ has a local maximum, $1$, at $0$, and is decreasing on $[0, \pi]$, hence its derivative is negative on $(0,\pi]$.

Set $g(x) =\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin cx}{cx}&\text{if}\enspace x\ne 0,\\1&\text{if}\enspace x=0.\end{cases}$

Actually, we have $g(x)=f(cx) $, so that $g'(x)=cf'(x)$.

We have $g(0)=f(0)$ and, since $f'(x)<0$ on $(0,\pi]$, we have
 $$\begin{cases}g'(x)<f'(x)&\text{if}\enspace c>1,\\
g'(x)>f'(x))&\text{if}\enspace c<1\end{cases}$$
Now, a classical corollary of the *Mean Value theorem* states that, on $(0,\pi]$,

- $g(x)<f(x)$ in the first case,
- $g(x)>f(x)$ in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor at $x=0$, $$\;\dfrac{\sin (cx)}{cx}=1-\frac{c^2 x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Is this sufficient for your needs ?

Comment: I haven't studied Taylor yet but it is interesting indeed!

Comment: Close to $0$, $\sin(x)\approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$. This is what I used. Don't worry : you will study Taylor very soon and I hope that you will love as much as I do for more than sixty years ! Cheers and good luck in your studies :-)

Comment: Be sure that you are very welcome !